# How to make hover styling with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

My website css has the sections of div1, img, ul, and ul li. I have it set up so that you see the country list and when you click it shows you the sub region and flag image. I want a hover over just the country, but it goes over all three. I am using the hover on the ul li right now, but I need to reference the country list api, like I was able to for the other two. How do I create that reference in javascript?[Here's the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lilyandtwitch/5tcfhmg3/2/)

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var respJSON = [];
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            resp = this.responseText;
            respJSON = JSON.parse(resp);

            html = document.getElementById("list");
            html.innerHTML = "";

            for(var i=0; i< respJSON.length; i++){
                html.innerHTML += "<li id="+i+" onClick='clickMe("+i+")'><u>" + respJSON[i].name + "</u></li>"

            }
        }
    }
    xhttp.open("GET", "https://restcountries.com/v2/all", true);
    xhttp.send();
   
function clickMe(index) {
  document.querySelectorAll('#list img').forEach(
    function(item) {
      item.remove();
  });
     document.querySelectorAll('#list div1').forEach(
    function(item) {
      item.remove();
  });
        li = document.getElementById(index);
        img = document.createElement("img")
        img.src = respJSON[index].flag;
        li.append(img);        
        let div = document.createElement("div1");
        div.innerText = respJSON[index].subregion;
        li.append(div);
}
```

Comment: Can you set this up as a jsfiddle ? So it can be answer better.

Comment: I'm not sure how to add a jsfiddle?

Comment: Here. https://jsfiddle.net/ 
You can add html,css, js then click save to generate a link afterwards append the link to your question here.

Comment: ok I think I got it

Comment: ...I want a hover over just the country, "but it goes over all three"

What three are you talking about here.

Comment: so it makes the country name, the flag image and the sub region all increase in size. I just want the hover over the country name and the flag and sub region to stay the same

Comment: Okay I see. Gonna add an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's happening that way because the country flag image is also child in the `li` tag you referenced in the css.

So what you can do is to add a class to the `u` tag in the `li` e.g. `'country-name'`. See below:

```js
// ...
for(var i=0; i< respJSON.length; i++){
    html.innerHTML += "<li id="+i+" onClick='clickMe("+i+")'><u class='country-name'>" + respJSON[i].name + "</u></li>"
}
// ...
```

Then in the css, change the `ul li:` to `.country-name`, see below

```css
.country-name:hover{font-size: 3em}
```

Test here: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lbaj35oe/1/)

Answer (score 1):

if you wanna apply hover effect to a btn just copy btn's class/id

and code snippet for your ref

```css
#hover:hover{
background : purple;
}
#hover{
background : black;
color : white

}
```

```html
<button id="hover"> HOVER ME </button>
```

Tell me is it ok or not

Comment: It probably would work, but it's not a button, it a list that you can just click on

Comment: oh ok same for ul li

Answer (score 1):

List:

```css
#hover-eff li {
color : green;
}
#hover-eff li:hover {
color : purple;
}
```

```html
<ul id="hover-eff">
<li> List - 1 </li>
<li> List - 2 </li>
<li> List - 3 </li>
<li> List - 4 </li>
<li> List - 5 </li>
</ul>
```

So its a code snippet list

Comment: It adds the hover, but still causes the flag and sub region to change also